# Centering span with bg-image in an anchor tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to center a  element (which display an icon via background-image) inside an anchor tag. FF and Chrome are making their job perfect, but all IE versions are making me sick. Would be cool if someone of you has a trick for me.

You can find the correct centered firefox version here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3i62.png

And the incorrect IE version here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDPno.png

And here is my HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="show-more"><span class="show-more-arrrow"></span></a>
```

And my SCSS code:

```
.show-more{
        height: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(239, 239, 239, 1.0);
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 2px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -12px;
    }
.show-more-arrrow {
        background-image: url(../images/arrow-submenu-large-hover.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        height: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 16px;
}
```

The anchor tag has a computed with of 863px and the span a width of 16px.

Comment: Have you tried `background-position: center center;` ?

Comment: I added this style to the .show-more-arrow but it didn't made a change ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you use `position: absolute;` the span will be regarded as a block element, `position: absolute;` is useless, you can replace it with `display: inline-block;`, hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I have fount this hack to pass the css rules that IE and Chrome ignore.
Here is the code.

```
.show-more:not(*:root){
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(239, 239, 239, 1.0);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
}
.show-more-arrrow:not(*:root){ 
        background-image: url(../images/arrow-submenu-large-hover.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        height: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 16px;
}
```

Please let me know if that helped your case too.